# Aggregation filter and lookup on Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My first collection `employeecategory` is like below;

```
[{
    name: "GARDENING"
  },
  {
    name: "SECURITY"
  },
  {
    name: "PLUMBER"
  }
]
```

My second collection `complaints` is like below;

```
[{
  communityId: 1001,
  category: "SECURITY",
  //other fields
}, {
  communityId: 1001,
  category: "GARDENING",
  //other fields
}]
```

I am trying to join above tables and get the below result;

```
[{
  "count": 1,
  "name": "GARDENING"
}, {
  "count": 1,
  "name": "SECURITY"
}, {
  "count": 0,
  "name": "PLUMBER"
}]
```

Even if there are no records in collection 2 I need count. I tried below aggregation but didn't worked. If I removed match condition it is working but I need to filter on community id. Could some please suggest best way to do achieve this. Mongo DB version is 3.4.0

```
db.employeecategory.aggregate(
  [{
    $match: {
      "complaints.communityId": 1001
    }
  }, {
    "$lookup": {
      from: "complaints",
      localField: "name",
      foreignField: "category",
      as: "embeddedData"
    }
  }]
)
```

Comment: It'd be better to have text rather than images.

Comment: what's your output look like and what are you expecting?

Comment: You need to use `$match` **after** you do the `$lookup`. Before you actually `$lookup` there is no data there. Also note you are calling the output path `"embeddedData"`. So anything you reference from the "joined" data will be inside that path. i.e `"embedded.Data.communityId"`. And note that the field produced by `$lookup` will be an "array" so you will need to `$unwind` it. Simply removing the `$match` here will at least show you what the "joined output" looks like, and give a clearer picture of how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not possible to achieve both filtering for `communityId = 1001` and grouping without losing `count = 0` category in a single aggregation. The way to do it is first start from `complaints` collection, and filter the `communityId = 1001` objects, and create a temp collection with it. Then from `employeecategory` collection, `$lookup` to join with that temp collection, and `$group` with `name`, you will have your result at this point, then drop the temp table.

```
// will not modify complaints document, will create a filtered temp document
db.complaints.aggregate(
  [{
      $match: {
        communityId: 1001
      }
    },
    {
      $out: "temp"
    }
  ]
);

// will return the answer that is requested by OP
db.employeecategory.aggregate(
  [{
    $lookup: {
      from: "temp",
      localField: "name",
      foreignField: "category",
      as: "array"
    }
  }, {
    $group: {
      _id: "$name",
      count: {
        $sum: {
          $size: "$array"
        }
      }
    }
  }]
).pretty();

db.temp.drop(); // to get rid of this temporary collection
```

will result;

```
{ _id: "PLUMBER", count: 0},
{ _id: "SECURITY", count: 2},
{ _id: "GARDENING", count: 1}
```

for the test data I've had;

```
db.employeecategory.insertMany([
   { name: "GARDENING" },
   { name: "SECURITY" },
   { name: "PLUMBER" }
]);

db.complaints.insertMany([
   { category: "GARDENING", communityId: 1001 },
   { category: "SECURITY", communityId: 1001 },
   { category: "SECURITY", communityId: 1001 },
   { category: "SECURITY", communityId: 1002 }
]);
```